# Low Rank Approximation using Singular Value decomposition

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, linear-algebra

I was going through this research [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/trippe19a/trippe19a.pdf). This paper mentions that:
[image][image]

But upon searching and referring other sources I found that the low rank approximation of a matrix using SVD is given as:
[image]

Please explain the approach mentioned in the research paper

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

They only complicated a bit by splitting the SVD decomposition in the used components and the unused components.

Notice that `A = sum(U[:, i:i+1] * s[i] * V[i:i+1,:] for i in range(len(s))`,

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(10, 15)
U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(A)
assert np.allclose(A, U @ np.diag(s) @ V.T)
assert np.allclose(A, sum(s[i] * U[:, i:i+1] * V[i:i+1,:] 
                            for i in range(len(s))))
```

Notice that the left multiplication by `U[:, :M].T` will project the matrix onto a subspace of the `M` first left singular vectors. And then left multiplying by `U[:,:M]` brings the projected value to the original basis.

```py
M=6
assert np.allclose(U[:, :M] @ U[:, :M].T @ A, 
     sum(s[i] * U[:, i:i+1] * V[i:i+1,:] for i in range(M)))
```